# How to draw a boxplot in bokehjs

Tags: javascript, bokeh, boxplot

It seems that bokehjs didn't provide the chart api for boxplot like in bokeh(bokeh is a python library) described in here (http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/charts.html#box-plots). So how can I achieve the same thing using bokehjs?
  Thanks a lot in advance.